# Mapping two pairs of elements from the same tables using spirng JPA

Tags: java, spring, database, spring-data-jpa, spring-jdbc

I want to create a sql database for graphs. My idea is to create a table for Graph, node and edge. Each graph would have a list of nodes and edges. Each node would have list of edges that come into that node and list of edges that came out of it. Each Edge have and information from which node it came out and into which node it goes. I am getting an error - "Repeated column in mapping for entity: graph.data.entity.Edge column: node_id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")". I shouldn't join on node_id column? Should i use insert="false" update="false"
when using @JoinColumn for toNode?

My code:

Edge.java

```
@Entity
public class Edge extends AbstractEntity {


    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "node_id")
    private Node fromNode;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "node_id")
    private Node toNode;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "graph_id")
    private Graph graph;

    @NotNull
    private int weight;
```

Node.java

```
@Entity
public class Node extends AbstractEntity {

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "fromNode", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Edge> outEdges = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "toNode", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Edge> inEdges = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "graph_id")
    private Graph graph;
```

Graph.java

```
@Entity
public class Graph extends AbstractEntity {

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "graph", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "graph", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Edge> edges = new ArrayList<>();
```

'''

Answer (score 1):

Ok, just after i posted my question i understood what i was doing wrong. I had to simply rename columns that are efects of joining columns